# Chrome "Copy image" option grayed out in right-click context menu

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkit

While poking around on [Apple's Website](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard) using Chrome (23), I discovered that the "Copy image" context menu item was disabled (see screenshot). So it looks like Webkit has a new way of disabling this option. Does anyone know what it is?

[image: Screenshot of disabled 'Copy image' context menu item]

Comment: I see the same thing, although I can open the image in a new tab and "steal" it from there with one extra click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image has an inline style of `content: -webkit-image-set`. When I remove this, the "Copy Image" option becomes enabled.

**Code (shortened for readability):**

```
<img style="content:-webkit-image-set(url(http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com), 1, url(http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/), 2);" 
src="http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/">
```

> The idea behind the feature is to allow authors to provide multiple
>   variants  of the same image at differing resolutions, and to allow the
>   User Agent to  choose the resource that is most appropriate at the
>   time.

http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/111637

Also see: http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2012/html5-urgently-needs-adaptive-images-mechanism/

Note that the inability to right-click and copy the image appears to be merely a side effect of the style, not an anti-download mechanism.